# How To Solve $5 = t - 2 \cos t$ for $t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Title says it all.  I'm doing Differential equations and got to this last step and completely forgot my algebra.

Comment: You could solve this numerically or graphically but I doubt that an exact solution in closed form exists.

Comment: Can you take a photo or scan of what you have already done and add that to the question? Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the DE? Are you looking for a closed form, or an approximate solution?

Comment: WA gives approx ( 3.016.., 4.416.., 6.761 ) numerical solutions for t. But for what DE is this a solution? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%3Dt-+2+cos+t

Answer (score 0):

This equation

$$t - 2\cos (t) = 5$$

is of transcendental type. $t$ can be calculated with numerical methods only.